# Where is the correct place to load a javascript function so it is applicable for ajax loaded pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Right now I have a:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('form').submit(function() {
  ...
  });
});
```

But this only works for the parent page.  If I load a document with .load() or .ajax() the submit() function for the form is not applicable.  So I take it I'm not supposed to use .load() or I'm not supposed to use it on window.  Where is the correct location if I want the .submit() it to work for ajax loaded documents?

**Solution:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
      ...
   });
 });
```

In solution: `this` still references the form as noted by Jquery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Note for anyone else who may run into an issue with .toLowerCase() or .toUpperCase(), these functions will break your script if the string is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with the `window.onload`, but you should generally use `document.ready` with jQuery.

It has something to do with the fact that event handlers are only bound to the elements that match the selector at the time of binding, and `$('form')` only matches the forms on the page **now**, not any forms you might add later.

The solution is to delegate the event to an element that exists now, and filter for target elements, and you'd do that like so :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
       ...
    });
)};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have quite a few functions along with submit().  Are there any changes that can be recognized to document when a page is loaded through ajax?

Comment: Delegated event handler are the way to go with dynamic content, the only other option would be add new event handlers to each inserted element after it's inserted.

Comment: I ran into the same issue using .on('submit', 'form') as ('form').submit().  It works for the parent page but no form on the loaded document.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, as this delegates to the document and should work with any form, present and future.

Comment: You're right, something is wrong because when I changed the code to just return false it stopped the form from submitting.  Does `this` still reference the form when using the .on() ?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, thanks for your help.  I had a `$(this).attr('method').toLowerCase()` and apparently toLowerCase breaks the script if method is not set.